# How can I get salary data on the gamer population in the US and/or Europe?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, europe, population, games

I am trying to conduct a study on the gaming population in the world for market research purposes.  I want to know what the average % of income is spent on gaming (hard/soft ware).

Are there any open source data where I can extract salary mean/sd statistics from a sample population of gamers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing legitimate market research, you should expect to pay for this data based on the value it provides to your business planning.

You are unlikely to find this data given away for free, or if it is, it probably is not reliable for market research because of data collection methodology problems.

I know that this is not much of an answer, but if I put it as a comment instead of an answer then this will continue to hang out in the "unanswered" questions queue, and that's a drag.

Given my way, this would be closed as "too broad" but we've generally been permissive about data request questions on this site, so...